# overriding displayOption to color certain lines according to a value from displayMethod

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am trying to override the `displayOption` on my form so that I color certain lines following certain conditions, When my condition was related to a normal field I had no problem with that, example code:

```
public void displayOption(Common _record, FormRowDisplayOption _options)
{
 if (_record.(fieldnum(MY_Table,My_Field))=="YES")
 {
  _options.backColor(WinAPI::RGB2int(161,161,255));
 }
  super(_record, _options);
}
```

but my problem is, I want to make a condition on a displayMethod not a normal field

Comment: Is it a table display method or a form datasource display method? If it's on a table, it should work on your initial load, but as data changes it might not and would probably give you some weird behavior. What does it do?

Comment: It's a table display method, if it should work, how can I even call it instead of the field?

Comment: Just cast `_record` to your actual table buffer. So if it was SalesTable, you would create a `SalesTable salesTable;` then do `salesTable = _record as SalesTable`, then `if (salesTable.tableDisplayMethod() == "whatever")`.

Comment: Great! I changed my comment to an answer to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A display method will work, you just need to cast the `Common _record` to your table buffer, then you can access the table method.

So if it was `SalesTable`, you would create:

```
SalesTable      salesTable;

salesTable = _record as SalesTable;
if (salesTable.yourTableDisplayMethod == "whatever") { // Do something }
```

Then you can use the display method as normal.